# Gulp-connect w/ subfolders

Tags: node.js, gulp

So here's an example of my `templates` folder structure

```
--myTemplate
  --leadpages-template
    --index.html
--myTemplate2
  --leadpages-template
    --index.html
->myTemplate3
  --leadpages-template
    --index.html
```

I have a series of subfolders, each representing a different template. A mandatory child of that subfolder is another folder named `leadpages-template`, required by LeadPages™ Marketplace Templates.

I've got a global gulp job that watches all the things, then runs various tasks like zip-file creation, SASS compilation, JS concatenation, etc. Each of these tasks are ultimately scoped the subfolder under which the watched file was changed.

The problem I'm having is with the gulp-connect task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: './',
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

If I serve up my root folder, I'm able to access:

```
http://localhost:8080/myTemplate/leadpages-template
http://localhost:8080/myTemplate2/leadpages-template
http://localhost:8080/myTemplate3/leadpages-template
```

What I want to be able to do is simply access:

```
http://localhost:8080/myTemplate
http://localhost:8080/myTemplate2
http://localhost:8080/myTemplate3
```

In the past, I've done this @ the template level with multiple roots, e.g. `root: ['./','leadpages-template']`. But now, I've moved the connect job up to the root templates folder, so I'm not sure how I'd serve up something like: `root: ['./', './**/leadpages-template']`

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Gulp-connect-multi appears to have that functionality

https://github.com/torifat/gulp-connect-multi

Comment: Sorry for late response. Got sidetracked on other work. I can see how to do this across multiple ports, but not the same port.